# access denied in spring application on GAE

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine

from a couple of days my application deployed on GAE was in error with the message

```
ERROR:Context initialization failed
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader[ContextLoader.java:215 2015-03-13 16:48:42,389@Request E088823F)
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager'
defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/modulo-spring.xml]:
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'fabbricaSessioni'
while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory';
nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'fabbricaSessioni':
Post-processing of the FactoryBean's object failed;
nested exception is java.security.AccessControlException:
access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.com.sun.proxy")
```

seems like Google has made some update that fails the spring's proxy creation.

I've searched a lot, but I haven't found anything....

this is my applicationcontext.xml

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory">
    <ref local="fabbricaSessioni" />
  </property>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
  <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:google:mysql://xxxxx"/>                         
</bean>
<bean id="fabbricaSessioni" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
    <property name="dataSource">
    <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="hib-persistence" />
  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
  </property>
  <property name="jpaDialect">  
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />  
  </property>
  <property name="jpaProperties">
    <props>
      [hibernate props]
    </props>
  </property>
</bean>
<tx:advice id="advice1" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
  <tx:attributes>
    <tx:method name="search*" read-only="true" />
    <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true" />
    <tx:method name="*" />
  </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
  <aop:advisor advice-ref="advice1" pointcut="execution(* org.somepackage.*.*(..))" />
  <aop:advisor advice-ref="advice1" pointcut="execution(* org.otherpackage.someclass.*(..))" />
</aop:config>
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: seems that you're using restricted classes from `com.sun.proxy` in your `fabricaSessioni`

Comment: I am not using any class from this package, almost not directly...

Comment: you're using AOP, that by default uses proxies. try to configure with CGLIB. see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

Comment: @igor-artamonov from your link:
      "To force the use of CGLIB proxies set the value of the proxy-target-class attribute of the <aop:config> element to true"

i've done, but the error still remains